# Quantitatively speaking, what's the most popular area of computer science research?

Tags: research

Like [this one](https://espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/roeder-feature-economists-1.png?quality=90&strip=info&w=575&ssl=1), for example, but for computer science. Maybe some survey of that kind was conducted for CS as well?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  I'm not sure whether this question is suitable for our site (any community votes?).  Our site is for technical questions about computer science (see our [help/on-topic]), and I'm not sure that what's popular falls within that ambit. If you want to give it a try: we need questions to be self-contained, and we'll need you to define what you mean by "most popular".  What metric do you want to use?  Also, what research have you done, and what motivates your question or how will you use answers?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-mission/what-are-the-most-popular-computer-science-topics-at-stanford-cedc33685a2d